# Can I make those three SQL queries fit into just one?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to count the number of positive, neutral, negative feedbacks.

I have those 3 queries that look very much alike. Is there a way I can put all this into one query? Or is it the most concise way of doing it?

Thanks in advance, regards.

```
$total_positive_seller = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM feedback 
           WHERE seller='$user' AND feedback='positive'"));
$total_neutral_seller = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM feedback 
           WHERE seller='$user' AND feedback='neutral'"));
$total_negative_seller = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM feedback 
           WHERE seller='$user' AND feedback='negative'"));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to count appearances, your use of `mysql_num_rows` is rather inefficient. It would be better to use the `count(*)` functionality of MySQL like in the following query:

```
SELECT feedback, count(*) AS `count` 
  FROM feedback 
  WHERE seller='$user' 
  GROUP BY feedback
```

This gives you something that should look like the following

```
feedback | count
----------------
positive |   12
neutral  |   8
negative |   3
```

You can afterwards parse this like any other query-result in a row-wise fashion.

**EDIT**

If you want to address each entry seperatly in your following code you can use something like the following. After this code you can reference all entries, e.g., by `$result['positive']`.

```
$qres = mysql_query( 'SELECT ...' );
$result = array();
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $qres ) ) {
  $result[ $row['feedback' ] ] = $row['count'];
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. And how would I count say, the number of positive feedback?

Comment: Sorry, I'm struggling with this `AS` command. Am I supposed to do something like `count(positive)`? I am not sure of the syntax.. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @alexx0186 The `AS` keyword simply assigns a name to that column. If you drop, you could not address this column as `$row['count']` after parsing the result with `$row=mysql_fetch_array($result)`, for example. The query above counts the respective entries for _all_ values present in `feedback`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. If I understood well, I won't be able to assign the count of positive feedback to `$positive_count=....` for example. Please correct me if i'm wrong. Thanks a lot. Regards

Comment: @alexx0186 You still may parse all rows and assign the appropriate row`s count-column to `$positive_count`. I'm not sure I understand you problem now.

Comment: All I want is `echo $total_positive_seller`, `echo $total_negative_seller` etc. Regards

Comment: @alexx0186 see my last edit. I don't use your variable names, but you can access the values in a similar fashion.