# How to echo the result of count(*) AS in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the count(*) AS, as an alternative to mysql_num_rows(). 
I get a count for all 3 kinds of feedback (positive, negative and neutral).

But I don't know how to assign the count of, say, positive feedback to a variable that I would call `$positive_feedback` and then, echo it. How can you do this with the following example?

I have this:

```
SELECT feedback, count(*) AS `count` 
FROM feedback 
WHERE seller='$user' 
GROUP BY feedback
```

which gives something like that:

```
feedback | count
----------------
positive |   12
neutral  |   8
negative |   3
```

Comment: (Possibly superfluous) follow-up of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667343/can-i-make-those-three-sql-queries-fit-into-just-one

Comment: Yes, I approved the other answer even though it didn't exactly answer my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query($query);  // with your query.

$feedback=array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $feedback[$row['feedback']]=$row['count'];
}
```

It will give an array consisting  of feedback['positive'],feedback['negative'] and so on with count stored in each.

Comment: Woops. Almost forgot. Regards

Answer (score 2):

Use Count(1), not Count(*), it's faster because the SQL engine can just use the count values from the counting B-Tree index and does not need to ever access any other values. If you plan to make this query a lot, make sure you add an index on the *feedback* tuple.

```
$query = "SELECT feedback, count(1) AS `count`...";
$result = mysql_query($query, $link); // don't forget to share your db conn

$feedbackArr = new array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $feedbackArr[$row['feedback']] = (int)$row['count'];
}

echo "Positive Feedback: \n";
print_r($feedbackArr);
```

Comment: He is continuing from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667343/can-i-make-those-three-sql-queries-fit-into-just-one) . He needs all feedbacks.

Comment: Ok, then using a GROUP BY is clearly better than 3 separate queries. I'll amend my response.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. No problem, since I didn't specify it in this post. I finally understood how I can do it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

With PDO it will look something like this:

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=%;dbname=%"; // insert your host and dbname

$db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password); // insert your username and pass

$sql = "
  SELECT 
    feedback, count(*) AS `count` 
  FROM 
    feedback 
  WHERE 
    seller='$user' 
  GROUP BY feedback
";

$feedback = array();
foreach ( $db->query($sql) as $row ) {
  $feedback[ $row['feedback'] ] =  $row['count'];
}

// result in here
print_r ($feedback);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I have tried with the mysql_* functions and will now switch to PDO's. Regards

Comment: @alexx0186 Unless you want a portable code  which you want to use later with another database system, PDO is not necessary.

Comment: @ngen, changing db system it's not the only reason of using PDO. For example, I use different db-systems in different projects. PDO is easier because it's the universal syntax, and I don't need to learn php functions for mysql, and for pgsql